# Mahara is not sending welcome email

Tags: email, phpmailer, mahara

I am trying to figure out why my Mahara is not sending welcome emails or emails when a user grants access to other users. User registration works normally and users receive welcome emails, but when I as an administrator try to add the new user it works but I get the message Error sending welcome email and the user does not receive the email.

Resetting the password via email works fine.

Error message I get:

> EmailException: Couldn't send email to "Name Surname" with subject You have been given access to 1 portfolio by "Name Surname". Error from phpmailer was: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. in `/var/www/mahara/web/lib/user.php:920`

```
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/mahara/web/notification/email/lib.php(104): email_user()
#1 /var/www/mahara/web/lib/mahara.php(1819): PluginNotificationEmail::notify_user()
#2 /var/www/mahara/web/lib/activity.php(996): call_static_method()
#3 /var/www/mahara/web/lib/activity.php(1055): ActivityType->notify_user()
#4 /var/www/mahara/web/lib/activity.php(89): ActivityType->notify_users()
#5 /var/www/mahara/web/lib/activity.php(231): handle_activity()
#6 /var/www/mahara/web/lib/cron.php(201): activity_process_queue()
#7 {main}
```

It should not be the authentication problem, the server is normally sending emails (when users manually registers or reset their password).

Comment: We can't really help without seeing code. If you're sending through gmail, then it's likely to be one of gmail's extra security measures, as described in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide.

Comment: We are sending emails trough office365.com i've read this about security measures, but what is confusing, the emails are just partialy sending (if users do the registrations by itself, they are getting emails normally).
Which code would help?

Comment: I don't know what you mean – emails are sent or not, you can't partly send one. The code that does the sending, so we can see how you're doing it.

Comment: Some of them are sent (as I wrote, if the students do self registration, they are getting normally emails), in other case if I as an administrator try to add new student, in this case, student will not be notified (they should get an welcome email).
I'am not sure which script or code doing this task, so if there are some mahara admins would be really helpfull.

Comment: Right, that's why I suggested you ask on a Mahara forum, rather than here which is more generic programming issues.